# 1st century Hellenistic Jewish interpretation of Proverbs 8:22( LXX)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, theology, mishlei

Proverbs 8:22 says that Wisdom is created by God. If so, is God without wisdom before he created wisdom?

Other Jewish texts ( though uninspired),also talks about God's wisdom as created by God.

I want to know what is the interpretation of the Hellenistic Jews about Proverbs 8:22.Do these Jews believe that there is a point wherein God is not wise?

Comment: Hmmm. Is Hellenistic Jewish interpretation of scripture on topic?

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe as a history question?

Comment: @DoubleAA I would think so, (and I am often on the stricter side of topicness debates).

Answer (score 3):

The logic would appear to be that "wisdom" as something that exists within the universe and is knowable by human beings has to be a creation of Hashem. Since Hashem is outside the universe and basically not understandable and knowable by human beings, then "wisdom" as something within the universe has to be created just as the sun, the moon, the stars and the laws of the torah and of nature must be created. Similarly, the acquisition of knowledge means that after **people** acquire knowledge, they can then acquire wisdom.

What the Hellenists might or might not understand about Hashem does not really matter in this respect. The Hellenist understanding of "gods" is more on the line of superpowerful people with magic powers (such as the Greek myths) rather than our understanding of what Hashem "is". In that respect, Hashem could have created such beings or people could have developed powers that later people thought made them "gods". Just as primitive people regarded the chiefs or shamans of the tribes (or like the Egyptians regarded Par'oh).

This is actually from what I have learned about the pagan myths and the descriptions of the "gods" from the Greek, Norse, and other writings. A typical example would be the Iliad and the description of the actions of the "gods" in the original "beauty" contest that led to it.

Of course more details of this would not really be appropriate for this site.

Comment: So God is not wise?

Comment: @DoubleAA "wisdom" in this sense is a human trait. We can ascribe human traits to Hashem as an attempt to understand things but it is only a limited attempt. It is also like talking about Hashem's "arm" or "compassion" or any other trait that we try to understand.

Comment: `What the Hellenists might or might not understand about Hashem does not really matter in this respect` Well the whole question was about them. You have refused to provide the info. that the OP requested, and thus this is not an answer.